# exception_notification settings not being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following in my `development.rb`, `staging.rb`, and `production.rb`

```
config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[Exception] ",
    :sender_address => %{"XXX" <XXX@example.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{XXX@ezample.com}
  }
```

These settings are not being taken by the Exception Notifier gem. It still uses the defaults.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set the ActionMailer `delivery_method` and also set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` and `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`?

Comment: Yes I have. All of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm just skimming over https://github.com/rails/exception_notification it seems the `:email` is not necessary?

```
Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "[Exception] ",
  :sender_address => %{"XXX" <XXX@XXX.com>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{XXX@XXX.com}
```

**Edit:**
The above only works for the gem `exception_notifier` (which is what is checked out via `gem install exception_notifier` (disregard the misleading github URL)

You do however probably want to use the newer gem: `gem install exception_notification` which is the name of the newer gem (the one this has evolved to)

Comment: That repo is outdated, the gem repo has been [here](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) for some time.

Comment: Ah, the gem still pulls from the old repo - but it is not being maintained.

Comment: @PinnyM: I see, that is strange

Comment: Weird. I suppose I should tell it to pull directly from the new repository.

Comment: Another solution, put this in your gemfile: 

    gem 'exception_notification', :git => 'git://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification.git'

Comment: I suppose the problem is they are two differently named gems. One is named exception_notifier and the other is exception_notification